# Forces applied to relative ball sizes

Tags: objective-c, iphone, vector, sprite-kit

In my code I have a ball that begins to fall and every time you tap on it it applies the code below. This works perfectly on the iPhone but I am also developing for iPad. Now on the iPad the balls have to be larger obviously and I want the same affect applied to those balls too. I tried doing the math to get the relative forces to the size of the ball and I know I did the math correct but there must be a more simple way to accomplish this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
/* Called when a touch begins */

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

// if ball is tapped apply impulse
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"ball"]) {
    node.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 15);
    [node.physicsBody applyImpulse:
     CGVectorMake(0, 50)];

    [GameState sharedInstance].easyScore += 1;
    [_lblEasyScore setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [GameState sharedInstance].easyScore]];

    NSLog(@"ball pressed");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Create private CGVector variable.
CGVector ballApplyImpulse;

//In your start method.(initWithSize, didMoveToView etc)
if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )//iPad Detected
{
    ballApplyImpulse = CGVectorMake(0, 100);//I haven't tested values. You can test yourself for true values.
}
else//iPhone Detected
{
    ballApplyImpulse = CGVectorMake(0, 50);
}

//In your on touch method
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"ball"]) {
    node.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 15);
    [node.physicsBody applyImpulse:ballApplyImpulse;

    [GameState sharedInstance].easyScore += 1;
    [_lblEasyScore setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [GameState sharedInstance].easyScore]];

    NSLog(@"ball pressed");
}
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks man! And I'm guessing that that would also work for the velocity in the touch method?

Comment: You are welcome, Yes that works for the velocity too.

Comment: Ok cool! Sorry just one more question, should I use it for the size changes of the nodes between iPhone and iPad? I know how to do it with sprites but I'm having trouble with the labels, would using this work too or is there an easier way?

Comment: You can use ipad, iphone detect code in everywhere.